# PHP str_replace() - Replace with space alternative?

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I came across a need today to use str_replace() to replace all hyphens in a string with spaces. Easy enough:

```
$string = "Some-test-string";
$string = str_replace('-', ' ', $string);
```

The thing is, using `' '` (string with empty space) in the "replacement" part of `str_replace()` just feels so dirty. Also seems brittle... Looks ugly too.

Is there no better option? I tried using a regex pattern in the "replacement" section but that didn't work, it came out literal.

Ideally, something like this would be great if possible:

```
$string = "Some-test-string";
$string = str_replace('-', '/\s/', $string);
```

Thanks!

**Edited:** Replaced all preg_replace() calls with str_replace() per suggestion.

Comment: You could use the hex value for space: ```preg_replace("/[-]+/", "\x20", $string);```, but I don't know if that makes it cleaner

Comment: You would be better off with str_replace for this. I would not worry about it looking brittle or ugly so long as it works and is easily understood. I would use ' ' instead of " ".

Comment: Abdullah Bakhsh - That replaces with a literal \x20.. I should clarify that I want the space in the string... just trying to find an alternative way to represent the replacement in the preg_match() call.

Comment: Thanks John Fawcett - A few minutes after I posted this, I had changed it to str_replace because I realized the pattern was not advanced enough to require preg_match()... I'll update my question to reflect that!

Comment: Well `\s` is a space, tab, or new line, there's no way for PHP to know which character you are expecting there (or no way that I know of). The `' '` should be fine, you could input the HTML entity if this is for a browser, `&nbsp;`, or `&#160;`.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason to use regular expressions in this case. Why not use a simpler function, e.g. [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)?

```
$string = "Some-test-string";
$string = strtr($string, '-', ' ');
```

Comment: Thanks ShiraNai7 - I had already switched out to using str_replace() once I realized that that regex pattern was too simple to require preg_replace(). I have updated my question to reflect that.